# Fullscreen infinite scrolling background

Tags: css, css-animations, translate-animation, background-size

I'm trying to implement a full-screen infinite scrolling background effect, which must extend on the entire height and width of the viewport.

Here's the [demo](http://www.bootply.com/8bhwOz93ZL).

The solution I've tried was to take a wrapper element that has `100vh` and `100vw` of the viewport, then place 2 `div`s inside it, 100% of its height, that have the same background-image and `background-size: cover` property. The size of the image I've used is: *1,920px × 808px*.

Then I've applied the following animation on the wrapper element:

```
@keyframes infiniteScrollBg {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}
```

But the problem is that on some viewport sizes, the images are not repeating correctly (because of `background-size: cover` property):

[image].

Here's the full code I've tried:

```
<div class="animated-scene">
    <div class="animated-scene__frame animated-scene__frame-1"></div>
    <div class="animated-scene__frame animated-scene__frame-2"></div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.animated-scene {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    min-height: 400px;
    animation: infiniteScrollBg 50s linear infinite;
 }

 .animated-scene__frame {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background-size: cover;
     background-color: #4277a3;
     background-image: url('https://andreivictor.ro/codepen/fullscreen-infinite-scroll-bg/fullscreen-bg');
}
```

Do you have any idea on how could I implement this effect?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used an image element just to use the auto height of it.

Then I use a backgroiund on a pseudo that gives the ability to repeat itself as many times as needed

I have set 2 different containers with different aspect ratios to more easily check the result on different screens

```css
.container {
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

#ctn1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

#ctn2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 350px;
  left: 320px;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  animation: scroll 5s infinite linear;
}

.inner:after {
  content: "";
  height: 500%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;

  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlK9o.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 20%;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
}


@keyframes scroll {
  from {transform: translateY(-100%);}
    to {transform: translateY(-200%);}

}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="ctn1">
    <div class="inner">
        <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlK9o.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="ctn2">
    <div class="inner">
        <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlK9o.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

A better solution with media query used to change the way the image is used.

Notice that background-size: cover is needed when both the aspect ratio of the image and the window is unknown. Since you know the aspect ratio of your image, you can control the display with a media query based on it.

Now, when it's needed, the image will adapt not to the width of the container, but to the height of it

```css
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 4/3) {
    .inner {
        height: 100%;
        width: auto !important;
    }
    .img {
       height: 100%;
       width: auto !important;
    }
}


.container {
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#ctn1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
}

#ctn2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 350px;
}

.inner {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  animation: scroll 5s infinite linear;
  display: inline-block;
}


.inner:after {
  content: "";
  height: 500%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlK9o.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 20%;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
}


@keyframes scroll {
  from {transform: translateY(-100%);}
    to {transform: translateY(-200%);}

}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="ctn1">
    <div class="inner">
        <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlK9o.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="ctn2">
    <div class="inner">
        <img class="img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlK9o.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great idea! I've implemented it in my example and it works: http://codepen.io/andreivictor/pen/xdPwXr.

Comment: Playing with your codepen, I have noticed the in extreme portrait ratios, the bottom of the screen is not covered. You should change the height of the pseudo element to more than 500% (let's say 1000%) and then the background size would be 100% 10%

Comment: Yeah, I've saw that downside: http://imgur.com/a/PfKCU. Also that 1000% height will make the element too big and maybe the animation will be a little choppy.  I think that a complete solution would be to use some different images, according to screen size (for mobile, for tablet and small desktops, another for full HD screens). However, this is the best answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Happy that it helped ! But I dont't think that this height makes the animation choppy. You could also swith to width: 50% (or less) on a media query

Comment: I have added a better solution.  Hope you like it !

Answer (score 5):

For scrolling background, I used background-position instead of using additional element and animate it using transform css properties.

**Why you might asked?**

1. Pattern will be seamlessly stitched by the browsers
2. cleaner HTML code. We just need one element to do this.

The only const doing this method is you need to know the dimension of image you are using.

Example :

```css
/*
  specify the scroll x (or y) with the width (or height) of the images
  In this case, the image dimension is :
  width: 1920px;
  height: 808px;
*/

@keyframes bgScroll {
  0% {
    background-position : 0px 0px
  }
  100% {
    background-position : 0px -808px
  }
}

.scrollingBG {
  display:block;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  background-image:url("https://andreivictor.ro/codepen/fullscreen-infinite-scroll-bg/fullscreen-bg.jpg");
  animation: bgScroll 20s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class='scrollingBG'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution perfectly fits with the problem.

Comment: Animating `background-position` is not very performant as it causes lots of repaints. It's better to use translations instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with aspect ratio. You're setting the aspect ratio to the view window, and not the image size. So your image ends up getting cut off at the view window aspect.

I worked around in your codepen by changing .animated-scene__frame to this:

```
 .animated-scene__frame {
    width: 100%;
    height:200vh; //easy way - increase height in animated div to prevent image cutoff. Ideally should be done through javascript using like a 3x multiple of the height of the image. Then just rely on background-repeat during the animation :)
    background-size:contain;
    background-color: #4277a3;
    background-image: url('https://andreivictor.ro/codepen/fullscreen-infinite-scroll-bg/fullscreen-bg-slide1.jpg');
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to just extend the picture 3 times, with:

```
@keyframes infiniteScrollBg {
 0% {
   transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 100%{
   transform: translateY(-66.66%);
 }
}
```

Use some image editor and create a large image with the same pattern, take a look of this site that I made [site](https://wearelife.foundation/2gether), there you will find some infinite background pattern

Comment: In your example the "moving" element has fixed dimensions: height - 396px and width - 5758px.... I'm trying to build something that takes 100% of the screen size and fits perfectly on it.

Answer (score 0):

You must use **background-position** property.
Here's fixed example http://codepen.io/azamat7g/pen/BRwRVV

Full code:

```css
@keyframes infiniteScrollBg {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }
}

.animated-scene {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  min-height: 400px;
  animation: infiniteScrollBg 50s linear infinite;
}

.animated-scene__frame {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom left;
  background-color: #4277a3;
  background-image: url('https://andreivictor.ro/codepen/fullscreen-infinite-scroll-bg/fullscreen-bg-slide1.jpg');
}

.bottom{
  background-position: top left;
}
```

```html
<div class="animated-scene">
  <div class="animated-scene__frame animated-scene__frame-1"></div>
  <div class="animated-scene__frame animated-scene__frame-2 bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't loop... at the the end of the animation the image jumps, because of the different background position.