# Infinite background scrolling using jQuery or Pure CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css

I'm having a heck of a time finding a solution to this, I have a large image 1920x4982.  I want it set as the background of a site and for it to scroll from bottom to top slowly and when it reaches the end of the image the top of the image is scrolled, just a simple infinite scroller.

I had tried several different methods using Keyframes, etc. but none of them worked.  One worked kind of but it cut the image off at the bottom of the screen instead of scrolling it infinitely.  I would show you the code I had tried but I nuked it out of frustration and no longer have it.

It has to be relatively simple and I'm just missing something, I'm working multiple jobs so my mind has just been all over the place lately.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: ***One worked kind of but it cut the image off at the bottom of the screen instead of scrolling it infinitely.*** perhaps you could post that code along with your question?

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: It kind of makes me wonder if you read the question at all, I already said I'd have shown you the code I had started but I nuked it out of frustration and thus no longe have it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fullscreen infinite scrolling background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43744887/fullscreen-infinite-scrolling-background)